# Image border extending to the side instead of to the bottom

Tags: html, css

It's tough to explain, but I'm using:

```
        <section class="courses">
            <figure>
                <img src="http://atlanta.eat24hours.com/files/cuisines/v4/chinese.jpg" alt="Asian" height="20%" width="20%" />
                <ficaption>Bok choi</figcaption>
            </figure>
    </section>
```

The fig caption is showing up to the right of the image instead of below it. I used the background color to indicate how long the border was:
[image: background]
<sub>(source: [gyazo.com](http://gyazo.com/5c94e96e58d7542da25b25a490a8052e.png))</sub>

And the figcaption is of course to the side as well.
[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7084ryt3/)
I want it so the border extends to the bottom so the fig caption shows correctly, like this:
[image: working]
<sub>(source: [gyazo.com](http://gyazo.com/7e42ff087c19e130c07e6d853f1bafcc.png))</sub>

Comment: I haven't looked at your CSS so I don't know if this is your issue, but you have a typo: "ficaption".

Comment: ^ Yep that was the issue. Fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

Insert a

```
<br>
```

before the caption, give image a fixed width, change figure to inline-block

http://jsfiddle.net/7084ryt3/4/

[edit] Ok, now i look stupid:-)

Comment: It would be better to have something like this in the stylesheet. If you add a line break and then want to have the caption show to the left or right, the line break will cause you trouble.

Comment: Didn't mean to make you look stupid. :) We all have to learn somehow... it wasn't long ago I was doing this!

Comment: i was referring to the typo;-)

Comment: Ah, gotcha. Easy to miss. I only noticed when I was mucking about with the fiddle and couldn't target the figcaption.